# Reflecting radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-engineering, antennas, radio-frequency

I have a laptop that I primarily use for music. I don’t want to have to bring my laptop to the basement every time I want to listen to music. I have bluetooth headphones and I was wondering if there was any way that I could somehow reflect the signal around barriers and into my basement. This may be a stupid question but I was just thinking about it. Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Could you not just use a male female usb adapter that has a cable linking the male and female parts then plug the bluetooth dongle into that?

Comment: i.e. using that extension cable so that the usb slot is actually in the basement.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to decide where to place reflectors so they bounce right around stairs and walls. And if you want to try it and mess around,you'll have a bunch of metallic things in places you won't want to see them. You have to do something else.

Bluetooth (BT) devices come in 4 categories or levels, and level 2 is what is used in most cellphones and laptops, maybe also in your headphone. Their nominal range is 33 ft, in line of sight comms, so with walls and floors it'll be less. They use the 2.5-2.6 GHz band, similar to WiFi, where when you have to go through walls and more than 2 floors you more or less loose it. The BT works for us in the same floor, and maybe a room or two part, but not more.

You have two alternatives: one is to try and find a not too expensive repeater. They exist but are mostly industrial purpose, level 1, and they will have a nominal range of 150-300 ft, so if you find one that's not too expensive you might. I have not tried it and it is possible they are not compatible with level 2s. So you can see if you can find them, I looked a little around and it's not obvious there's a solution. Try googling for BT repeaters, I saw something in [https://www.amazon.com/Miccus-Home-RTX-Bluetooth-Transmitter/dp/B00713RSE0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00713RSE0)

Or see if you can get WiFi/BT headphones instead.

Sorry, the laws of physics along with low power transmissions are a bear.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the repeaters, I have heard of these before but when I searched around for them it seemed like they were for only large apartment buildings or industry type places. But a confirmation that this might work is reason enough for me to dig a little deeper. Thanks much!